# Android SQLite 3, JOINS or multiple queries?

Tags: android, sqlite, join

I'm writing on a small Android App with SQLite 3 support. ATM I'm implementing some DB-Functions and asking myself if it is better have one big joined query or if it is OK to use multiple queries in respect to App performance.

Let's say I have a 3 Tables "drivers", "driven_runs", "race_disciplines". Every driven_run has a driver and a race_discipline. Let's assume I want to get all race disciplines by a certain driver in a certain discipline.

**Solution 1**

I already coded a function getDriver(driverID) with a Driver-Object in return and a function getRaceDiscipline(disciplineID) with a Race Discipline in return. So I would just create a function

```
public ArrayList<DrivenRun> getDrivenRunsOnDiscipline(short driverID, short disciplineID) {
    ArrayList<DrivenRun> drivenRuns = new ArrayList<DrivenRun>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_DRIVEN_RUNS + " WHERE " 
            + DBHelper.DRIVEN_RUNS_COLUMN_DRIVER_ID + "=" + driverID + " AND " 
            + DBHelper.DRIVEN_RUNS_COLUMN_RACE_DISCIPLINE_ID + "=" + disciplineID + ";";
    Cursor result = rawQuery(sql);
    if (result.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Driver driver = getDriver(driverID);
            RaceDiscipline discipline = getRaceDiscipline(disciplineID);
            DrivenRun run = new DrivenRun();
            run.setDriver(driver);
            run.setDiscipline(discipline);
            run.setResult("WHATEVER");
            drivenRuns.add(run);
        } while(result.moveToNext());
    }
    return drivenRuns;
}
```

in this case there would be 3 queries executed on after another but the coding is much more simple.

**Solution 2**

I would create one big joined query like

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM driven_runs CROSS JOIN drivers CROSS_JOIN race_disciplines WHERE driven_runs.driver_id=drivers.id AND driven_runs.race_discipline_id=race_disciplines.id"
Cursor result = rawQuery(sql);
```

and would manually create the Driver and DrivenRun Object.

This solution needs much more writing but only one query is executed (or does the DB executes 3 queries as well when joining 3 tables?)

Long story short, is it OK to go with solution 1 because in regards to performance there isn't much of a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, go for the simpler code until there's a good performance reason not to. Given that this is SQLite anyway, I don't think there's likely to be much performance difference, since the overhead for queries is pretty low.

Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 2):

You should use proper join syntax, then your query won't look so cumbersome:

```
SELECT THECOLUMNSYOUREALLYNEED
FROM driven_runs JOIN
     drivers
     on  driven_runs.driver_id=drivers.id join
     race_disciplines
     on driven_runs.race_discipline_id=race_disciplines.id
where driver.id = YOURDRIVEIDHERE and race_discipline = YOURDISCIPLINEIDHERE
```

Also, only return the columns that you need.  Second, insert the appropriate ids in the `where` clause.  Your version is returning everything, which is totally unnecessary.

This is a pretty simple query and it does what SQL databases do best -- joining large tables together.  Even with SQLite, you are probably better off letting the database do the work.  It is, at the very least, going to save some round trip communication from the database layer back to the application layer.

In a more sophisticated environment, the database will take advantage of multiple processors, multiple disks, and intelligently cache results to further optimize query response.